# Angular parameter types on jsdoc

Tags: angularjs, ide, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc

I'm wondering what are the "proper" parameter types on angular specified stuff within jsdoc?

Eg. if I have something like:

```
/**
 * Some comment
 *
 * @param {WhatHere} $http
 * @param {WhatHere} $timeout
 */
function FooBar($http, $timeout) {
}
```

What are the proper types for those $http and $timeout so that IDE (Web/PhpStorm) can autocomplete those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jetbrains products cannot do this by analyzing the code, there's too much magic in Angular's dependency injection system. However, you can do it by installing a typed library in at least Webstorm and PyCharm (probably PHPStorm and other Jetbrains products as well):

- Go to `Preferences` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `JavaScript` > `Libraries`
- Click the `Download…` button
- Select `Typescript community stubs` in the top-left dropdown (don't worry, it also works for JavaScript)
- Find angular.js and click the `Download and Install` button
- Click the `Manage Scopes…` button and add angular.js to your project by clicking in the second column and selecting `angular.js-DefinitelyTyped`.

Now you can annotate your code like this:

```
/**
 * @param {$http} $http
 * @param {$timeout} $timeout
 */
function FooBar($http, $timeout) {
}
```

[image: $http]
[image: $timeout]

Note that this trick works for all popular libraries that have a TypeScript community stub available!

Answer (score 0):

I will complement Blaise's answer, because lib name has changed, now it is: `angularjs-DefinitelyTyped`. Also, have a look [angularjs-DefinitelyTyped doc](https://definitelytyped.org/docs/angularjs--angular-mocks/modules/ng.html) to know which type to specify, example:

[image]
<sub>(source: [joxi.ru](http://joxi.ru/8ZrJ9wDtzMypAj?d=1))</sub>